# Oracle Apex RestFul Services

Tags: rest, oracle-apex

I'm trying to test the Sample services in APEX Restful services.

getting error 404 not found while the restful services are registered.

[image]

ORDS version: 21.3.1.r3012050

APEX version: 21.2.0

note that I registered the restful services as shown below

[image]

Comment: I found the answer in another thread. [ORDS Public User Locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466914/how-do-i-get-my-ords-sample-service-working)